# Custom _app.js file for a single directory in Next js

Tags: next.js

I have a folder in my next js application called "articles", in which I'd like to have *.mdx files. MDX is a markdown parser that generates JSX.

I'd like the pages in the articles directory to be styled a certain way, so I want to create an _app.js file with those styles. However, I don't want to put this in my main _app.js, since these styles are only relevant to the articles directory.

Is there a way to override the app only within a certain directory?

Answer (score 1):

You have the o create a Root component that every other component inside the articles directory will use, i.e.

```
pages
  |- RootComponent.jsx
  |- page1.jsx
  |- page2.jsx
```

And then you wrap page1.jsx and page2.jsx with RootComponent

Comment: The issue is those pages are mdx, not jsx. I can still wrap the component but it defeats the purpose of using a markdown parser.